# Accordian Jquery Events for Customised List forms

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, custom-list

Want to understand how do we differentiate Submit/save event in customized list forms.

eg:

When we are in Section 1 the submit/save should correspond to data being submitted in section1

when we are in Section 2 the submit/save should correspond to data being submitted in section 2 . Please let me know how to proceed on this

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Are you talking about an accordion, with each section having a form?  How is this a SharePoint issue? This sounds like an SO question.

Comment: Hi,Yes we want to implement SharePoint List Columns in Accordian View. e.g Column1 and column2 in Section 1  Column 3 and column 4 in section 4 . How do we implement it.  And the save button should correspond to respective sections when expanded

Answer (score 0):

You have to roll your own logic in that case, the default Save action saves and closes the form.

So if you want some sort of tabbed interface that allows the user to "save" then finally "submit" you need to create functions that do the following: the Save button would create a list item if you are on tab 1 otherwise it is an update to the list item, Submit is an update to the list item, and Cancel either redirects you back to where you were, or if on a different tab, deletes the created list item, then redirects you somewhere.

Comment: Hi Eric,Thanks for your reply. However its staged request form. Once we submit data in one particular section it triggers workflow and moves to next section where other person will come in and check the form and update data in section 2.

Comment: Then the normal save button should be fine, you'd probably want to send query string params in the workflow process so that the user hits the right tab. It wasn't clear in your question what you were trying to achieve.